# Nested arrays - how to add a row of elements to nested JavaScript array

Tags: javascript

I want to add the row

```
    ['2008',777,333]
```

to var fun and maintain the structure:

```
var fun = [
    ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
    ['2004',  1000,      400],
    ['2005',  1170,      460],
    ['2006',  660,       1120],
    ['2007',  1030,      540]
         ];
```

Using push or concat seems to destroy the structure.  Can this be done?

Comment: What did you try? Where is your effort?

Comment: The answers referred to DO NOT MAINTAIN THE STRUCTURE which is at the heart of this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fun.push(['2008', "1033", "554"]) //to add whole row
fun[2].push('555') // to add item into row 3 as the last item
```

Comment: Apologies - I was referring to the -1 vote - thanks for answering it

Comment: In fact - thanks again - it solved my problem immediately.